# October CMS Models - Overwrite save function

Tags: php, oop, octobercms

Good day,

I overwrote the save function of my October CMS model.

```
 public function save(Array $options=[])
```

When I tried to save, it threw an error.

> Declaration of MyCompany\MyPlugin\Models\MyModel::save(array $options = Array) should be compatible with October\Rain\Database\Model::save(array $options = NULL, $sessionKey = NULL)" on line 42 of /a/b/c/d/mysite/plugins/mycompany/myplugin/models/MyModel.php

So I modified the save function.

```
public function save(Array $options=[], $sessionKey=null)
```

Then I get this confusing error.

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to MyCompany\MyPlugin\Models\MyModel::save() must be of the type array, null given, called in /a/b/c/d/mysite/modules/backend/behaviors/FormController.php on line 251" on line 38 of /a/b/c/d/mysite/plugins/mycompany/myplugin/models/MyModel.php

So, if it's passing a null there, how are models saving, considering the class inheritance forces argument 1 to be an array?

Edit: Here is line 251 of /a/b/c/d/mysite/modules/backend/behaviors/FormController.php

```
$modelToSave->save(null, $this->formWidget->getSessionKey());
```

So the base class will accept nulls, even if type hinting requires Array, but upon overwriting the function, nulls are no longer accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method signature does not match the original `October\Rain\Database\Model` method signature. If you read the original [source](https://github.com/octoberrain/database/blob/master/Model.php#L559), you'll see that the default value for `$options` is `null`.

This is important, because it tells PHP the parameter value should be either an `array` or `null`. Presently, your function requires an `array` only.

```
public function save(array $options = null, $sessionKey = null)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't think the default parameter value can have a "do not accept nulls" effect.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think I've read it anywhere in the documentation until type hinting was introduced in PHP 7. But yeah, it's a thing.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best option is to use a model events https://octobercms.com/docs/database/model#events

```
public function beforeSave()
{
    $this->slug = Str::slug($this->name);
}
```

Comment: It's a better approach, and a better option do that with model Extender `Model::extends()`